# MultiValue Dict Key Error Django - Forms when trying to display DateField

Tags: python, django, datefield

I have a form with DateField - 'receivedon' attribute as below:

forms.py:

```
class PreDataForm(forms.ModelForm):


    journalname=forms.ChoiceField(required=True,choices=JOURNAL_CHOICES)

    articletype = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=ARTICLE_TYPES)

    granttype = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=GRANTS)

    receivedon=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model=PreData
        fields=['journalname','articlename','articlenumber','caname','camail','articletype',
                'country','affliation','granttype','status','receivedon']
```

I will be asking users to fill that date in html, normal procedure:

html:

```
                          <div class="center col-md-6">
                             Received On:
                             {{ form.receivedon  }}

                         </div>
```

Now i want to upload the date through django views like this:

views.py:

```
 if request.method=="POST":

        form=PreDataForm(request.POST or None)

        print request.POST['receivedon']


        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
```

One thing is that form is always invalid for `post` request, when i check `is_valid` function, other thing when I try to display `datefield` data using `request.POST['receivedon']` i am getting **Multi Value Dict Key Error**

Can any one help me with this? Thanks.

Traceback - Edit:

```
File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/django_project/jsmmetrics/views.py" in createdata
  55.         print request.POST['receivedon']

File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  85.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /metrics-jsm/create-data/
Exception Value: "'receivedon'"
```

Comment: can you post the traceback please so we can see what led to the error?

Comment: @adam jaamour, please check the trace back

Comment: Does this line print anything? `print request.POST['receivedon']` if it does can you tell me what it prints?

Comment: that is the line which raises 'multivalue...' exception. if i remove the line, form is always invalid even though data is valid. i think i'm missing how to handle datefield widget to get data

Comment: Maybe try doing `request.POST.get('receivedon')` instead, this will ensure that you don't get a MultiValueDictKeyError error

Answer (score 0):

You're not receiving the key `receivedon` in `request.POST`. You can do the following to avoid this error for this particular key:

```
request.POST.get('receivedon', <some default value>)
```